# Unit Testing Get with Include 'Value cannot be null'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I am unit testing a get call using Moq. I am using Automapper to pull data from a SQL database and map it into my view models. My method looks something like this:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<ViewParentTable> Get()
{
    Mapper.CreateMap<ParentTable, ViewParentTable>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<ChildTable, ViewChildTable>()

    IEnumerable<ViewParentTable> tableresult = db.ParentTable
         .Include("ChildTable")
         .Project().To<ViewParentTable>();

    return tableresult;
}
```

And my test looks something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Get()
{
    IEnumerable<ViewParentTable> returned = method.Get();
    mockContext.VerifyGet(m => m.ParentTable);
}
```

I have mocked the DbContext as such:

```
this.mockParentSet = new Mock<DbSet<ParentTable>>();
this.mockChildSet = new Mock<DbSet<ChildTable>>();

mockParentSet.As<IQueryable<ParentTable>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(mockParentData.Provider);
mockParentSet.As<IQueryable<ParentTable>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(mockParentData.Expression);
mockParentSet.As<IQueryable<ParentTable>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(mockParentData.ElementType);
mockParentSet.As<IQueryable<ParentTable>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(mockParentData.GetEnumerator());

mockChildSet.As<IQueryable<ChildTable>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(mockChildData.Provider);
mockChildSet.As<IQueryable<ChildTable>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(mockChildData.Expression);
mockChildSet.As<IQueryable<ChildTable>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(mockChildData.ElementType);
mockChildSet.As<IQueryable<ChildTable>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(mockChildData.GetEnumerator());

this.mockContext = new Mock<MyContext>();
this.mockContext.Setup(m => m.ParentTable).Returns(mockParentSet.Object);
this.mockContext.Setup(m => m.ChildTable).Returns(mockChildSet.Object);
```

I have filled both `ParentTable` and `ChildTable` with data.  If I remove the `Include("ChildTable")`, the test passes.  However, with the `Include("ChildTable")` in place an exception is thrown on the db call, `Value cannot be null`.  All non-nullable fields in both Child and Parent tables are populated, so I'm not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: I don't know how Moq deals with mocking `DbSet`, but with other mocking frameworks I've used you have to realize they are not actually a database, so they are not going to do the joins necessary to include the related data. instead, you have to load them with the fully-formed object graph so they can spit it back out as if a real database had joined the data.

Comment: Yes, I am handling that.  When I construct the test data, I loop through each element of `ParentTable` and assign `item.ChildItems` based on ids.  Similarly, I loop through each element of `ChildTable` and assign `item.ParentItem` based on id.

Comment: I don't think this test adds any value. Aren't you just testing AutoMapper at this point?

Comment: This is a simplified version of what I'm doing.  The point is it never gets to the `VerifyGet` because it throws an exception executing the method.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get it work by following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34857934/370307)

```
mockParentSet.Setup(m => m.Include(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(mockParentSet.Object);
```